# mysql_query() Is Returning Error "No Database Selected"?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a script that let's users update their passwords. It does this by first locating the entered email address of the user, then updates the password to whatever they create.  However, I'm getting a "no database selected" error from mysql_query().  The email address I'm testing is valid and is in the database, and my query syntax looks good.  I don't know what could be causing this. Any advice would be appreciated, thank you all in advance.

Furthermore, my form that is posting these values is ok, as I've looked over that many times.

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','calsheet_project','UUx[@]MoF4?F') or die("couldn't connect!");

$eml = $_POST['data'];
$newPassword = $_POST['data1'];
$cnewPassword = $_POST['data2'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = $eml") or die(mysql_error());
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query);
var_dump($fetch);

echo mysql_error();

if($fetch > 0) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE accounts SET password=$cnewPassword WHERE 
    email=$eml");
    echo "Password Reset!";
} else {
    echo "email address cannot be found.";
};

?>
```

If working correctly, it should update the password field for the associated email address of the user.  But, it's showing the error "no database selected."

Comment: THat's because you didn't select a database. And that's because you are using an obsolete, insecure API.

Comment: See: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php and also the big red box that says you shouldn't be using this API anymore. Any version of PHP that supports `mysql_*()` is end-of-life and not something you should be using even for learning purposes.

Comment: ^^^ shouldn't bother until you stop using that dangerous legacy code, but mysql requires strings to be quoted, and your not doing that

Comment: It would also be a good idea to not store passwords like this in a database. And please change the password of your database now.

Comment: It is hard to reply :-) first i want to see the form that you posted. Then are you sure that your php configuration enable the mysql extension library? try to see in phpinfo() if enable actually now a days we use mysqli the mysql is end-of-life already.

Comment: Thanks for all of the input and links, I've since started using PDO and everything works just fine.  I bet my PHP version doesn't support the outdated mysql_*() functions.  and yes, I'm changing my password!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code before you execute`mysql_query`

```sql
// select the query database
mysql_select_db("db_name");
```

and the PHP official said `mysql_connect()` is not good anymore for security reasons.

> Warning
>   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead,  > the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

for more details see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php